# GDB won't let me output my code sometimes?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gcc, makefile, gdb

So, I'm new to C++. I need to learn this language quick for school. But I'm walking against some issues that make it difficult to work with this language. I downloaded visual studio code and followed the steps given by my school. But now I have the problem that sometimes my code just won't print.

Here is an example of a piece of code that does print (btw, I use a "makefile" to run all of this):

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Ofcourse, just a simple "hello world" but still, it does print. Now I'll give an example of a piece of code that won't print:

```
// C++ program to sort an
// array using bucket sort
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
 
// Function to sort arr[] of
// size n using bucket sort

void bucketSort(float arr[], int n)
{
    cout << "hello" << endl;
    // 1) Create n empty buckets
    vector<float> b[n];
 
    // 2) Put array elements
    // in different buckets
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int bi = n * arr[i]; // Index in bucket
        b[bi].push_back(arr[i]);
    }
 
    // 3) Sort individual buckets
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sort(b[i].begin(), b[i].end());
 
    // 4) Concatenate all buckets into arr[]
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < b[i].size(); j++)
            arr[index++] = b[i][j];
}
 
/* Driver program to test above function */
int main()
{
    cout << "hello" << endl;
    float arr[]
        = { 0.897, 0.565, 0.656, 0.1234, 0.665, 0.3434 };
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    bucketSort(arr, n);
 
    cout << "Sorted array is \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

This is an example of a bucket sort I found online. First, the "n" on the `vector<float> b[n]` line, gave a red line, I chose the "ignore this error" option. Second, this code won't output anything. If I look into the "debug console" I find this error: ERROR: Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command "-exec-run". During startup program exited with code 0xc0000139.

When I looked online I saw some people give the advice to downgrade my gdb version. I want to try that, but I can't find out how to do that haha. Can someone help me get my visual studio code working? This is the most irritating part of programming to me.

Comment: The line `vector<float> b[n];` defined a [variable-length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), which is not supported in standard C++, but some compilers support them as an extension. If your compiler does not support them, you can use a vector of vectors (i.e. a 2D vector) instead, like this: `vector<vector<float>> b(n);`.

Comment: You generally cannot download an extension to a compiler to make it support additional things. The only thing you can do is to change the compiler. However, in this case, I don't recommend that you try looking for a compiler that supports variable-length arrays. I suggest that you stick with standard C++, by using a 2D vector instead, as described in my previous comment. That way, the code should also work on your current compiler.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bucket-sort-2/

Comment: Super helpfull stuff guys, thx! It's difficult to start to learn all this. I'm trying my best :).

Comment: Just to easy my mind guys, how do you let the bucket sort work with the 'vector<vector<float>> b(n);' line? Because I try that and I get the same exact error.

Answer (score 0):

> `ERROR: Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command "-exec-run". During startup program exited with code 0xc0000139.`

This error means that the program didn't start at all, i.e. died during process setup.

On UNIX this usually happens when the GDB [exec-wrapper](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Starting.html) dies. But I have no idea how VSCode sets up GDB and under what conditions it would die like this.

General advice:

- **if** you want to learn GDB, *and* you insist on using Windows, then learn GDB in a [WSL2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) environment.
- if you don't want to learn GDB, learn debugging using Visual Studio
- you should always learn "native" debugger for the OS you are using -- that way you avoid having to debug various "shims" which (imperfectly) emulate one environment inside another (as appears to be the case here).

Comment: `0xc0000139` is `STATUS_ENTRYPOINT_NOT_FOUND`, not a segmentation fault.

Comment: @ssbssa Thanks. I mis-remembered. Erroneous statement deleted.